# Work with custom product attribute without loading the product object itself

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, collection, product-attribute, product-collection

I need to manipulate a custom product attribute for almost all products in the database. Right now I have this:

```
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

        foreach ($productsCollection as $_product) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId());
            if ($product->getCustomizableonly() === null) {
                $product->setData('customizableonly', 0)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'customizableonly');
            }
        }
```

But the products are more than 2000 and therefore I don't want to load the product object itself, but to work just with the product object instance from the collection. The problem is that this obj. instance contains only 1/9th of the whole Data of the product object itself. And the `'customizableonly'` attribute is NOT part of that 1/9th.

How can I access the attribute without making unnecessary object loading. Or in general - how can this code be optimized to maximum, so it is not dramatically slow in case of 2000+ products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your collection like this.

```
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('customizableonly');
```

And here is an other way of updating all products at once so you don't have to call `saveAttribute` 2k times.
From what I understand, you want to set the value  for `customizableonly` to 0 for all the products that don't have that value.
Here goes:

```
$toUpdate = array();
foreach ($productsCollection as $_product) {
    if (is_null($_product->getCustomizableonly())) {
        //remember the id for update
        $toUpdate[] = $_product->getId();
    }
}

//update all products
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($toUpdate, array('customizableonly'=>0), 0);
```

This should get you a boost in speed.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks a lot! I just want to ask - in the 2nd solution I get an exception `Call to a member function getAttributeId() on a non-object in **C:\htdocs\hach_gk\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Action.php** on line **69**`. By debugging I found that the previous line `$attribute = $this->getAttribute($attrCode);` returns **false**. It cannot find the attribute or what ?

Comment: I think it tries to update an attribute value for a product that does not have that attribute. I mean, the product belongs to an attribute set that does not contain the attribute. And there are not 2 solutions. You should use both. Get the collection like I described, then loop through it and get the products for update.